# how to distribute the items to the width in relative layout

Tags: android, layout

I have 7 items, which aligned in one line and disturb to the width by weight parametr in layout. By link you find mockup.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fuftcx8w8s10bmk/tooltip.png

I can't align tooltip relative Circle. And try to convert linear layout to relative, disturb all items to the width and set parent for tooltip as Circel, after it use  android:layout_below="@id/imgCircle" but in relative layout hav't weight.

Main target - set tooltip triangle alignt to center of Circle item on every device. Now I use margin for this, but it works only on my xhdpi screen.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/navHead">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imgDash1"
            android:src="@drawable/div"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
            android:layout_weight="0.1" 
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imgCircle2" 
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dotempty"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imgDash2" 
            android:src="@drawable/div" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_weight="0.25/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imgCircle3"
            android:src="@drawable/dotnext" 
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imgDash3" 
            android:src="@drawable/div" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Dash"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imgCircle1"
            android:src="@drawable/dot"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imgDash4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
            android:src="@drawable/div"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" 
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
        android:text="@string/result"
        android:id="@+id/txtTooltip"
        android:background="@drawable/tooltip"
        android:layout_below="@id/navHead" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

Comment: image link isn't available.

Comment: A custom `ViewGroup` will probably be a better solution than trying to place standard items.

Comment: Can you explain with example, I'm newby in development and learn it less then month. I try to create app for learning and find new hard task everyday.

Comment: Screens of my app: https://disk.megafon.ru/p/SA3aJBA/ and https://disk.megafon.ru/p/jvPdJBA/ in the top of screen navHeader and I can't align tooltip with orange circle.